# How to overwrite window height and width from package.json in node webkit

Tags: node-webkit

Code from `package.json`:

```
{
    "main": "main.html",

    "name": "Test App",
    "window": {
        "toolbar": true,
        "width": 400,
        "height": 500,
        "position": "mouse",
        "resizable": true
    }
}
```

In `main.html` I have **javascript code to open new window**:

```
 window.open("http://www.example.com","mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=100");
```

But height and width of window is not at `width=100` and `height=100`.

I have also tried `window.resize(100,100)` in main.html but it didn't work.
Is there any way so that I can overwrite `height` and `width` of a new window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows opened using `window.open()` use the window settings from the manifest file (package.json).

If you use the nw.js Window object to create the window, instead of the DOM object, you can pass in window settings in manifest format to override the defaults.

```
var gui = require("nw.gui")
gui.Window.open('http://www.example.com', {  
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
});
```

Alternatively, if you must use the DOM `window.open` and need to control the defaults, you will need to handle the "new-win-policy" event and provide window settings using `setNewWindowManifest`:

```
// set up handler for new-win-policy event
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();

win.on('new-win-policy', function (frame, url, policy) {
    policy.setNewWindowManifest({
        width: 600, 
        height: 300
    });
});

// open window using DOM object, uses arguments set in event handler
window.open('http://www.example.com', '_blank', '');
```

Further documentation available here: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Window#new-win-policy